# Was my mozilla download corrupted after a system wake up?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, download

I have a windows 7 OS with a mozilla firefox browser. I had a large ISO file being downloaded on it while I carelessly put the system in standby without pausing the download. Although the download continued by itself after I resumed the system from standby could have it been corrupted ? 
Well the ISO download has not yet completed so I can' t test it!..

Thanks in advance

Sydney....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are dealing with large files. may i suggest you to use download managers such as [IDM](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) or [Free download manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If it continued with no issues, I would bet that it's fine. If it were going to have any issues, it would have failed to continue the download. It will check file integrity after it completes as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems in the past. Downloaded file behaves as correct but it wasn't. It is still possible that your download will be OK. If you have also checksum of original file, it is easy to verify it after download.